# Proving a Sequence Diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Let {${\alpha_n}$} be a sequence in $\mathbb R$ satisfying $|\alpha_n - \alpha_{n+1}|\geq c$ for some $c > 0$ and all $n \in \mathbb N$. Prove that the sequence {$\alpha_n$} diverges.

I've looked up a few examples on how to show a sequence diverges, where they talk about showing that one variation of the sequence goes to one limit, and another variation goes to a different limit, but I wasn't sure how to do that with this.

Comment: For once, a proof by contradiction might be a good idea. So, assume that $\alpha_n\to\ell$ when $n\to\infty$, then...

Comment: Thanks for the jumping-off point! I don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place. My professor despises proof by contradiction, so I often forget it's a valid strategy.

Comment: If you really want, you can avoid proof by contradiction by showing: For any $\ell$ and any $\varepsilon<\frac c2$ and any $n$, either $|\alpha_n-\ell| \ge \varepsilon$ or $|\alpha_{n+1}-\ell| \ge \varepsilon$. Then confirm that this implies the definition of diverging (which is a "for all $\ell$ there exists $\varepsilon$ such that for all $N$ there exists $n>N$" statement).

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't need to use contradiction. But you need to use *negation* or maybe a definition given by a professor for a sequence to diverge but I've found that teachers tend to omit this. A sequence $(a_n)$ diverges if for any $x \in \Bbb R$ there is a neighbourhood $V$ ( or $\epsilon \gt 0$)  such that given any $n \in \Bbb N$ there is a corresponding natural number $m_n \ge n$ such that $a_{m_n} \not \in V$ (or $|a_{m_n} - x| \ge \epsilon$ ). This in essence is the negation of the definition of a convergent sequence. But if you are unhappy in general with proofs by contradiction because you are not a fan of the *"law of the excluded middle"* then my friend you are going to have trouble moving forward.

Let's get to your question.

For any $x \in \Bbb R$ there exists $\epsilon = \frac c 3 \gt 0$ such that given any $n \in \Bbb N$ there is a corresponding natural number $m_n$ fulfilling the prescribed conditions. This must be proven. For any $n$ either $a_n \in \{y \in \Bbb R \ | \ |y - x| \lt \frac c 3\}$ or $a_n \not \in \{y \in \Bbb R \ | \ |y - x| \lt \frac c 3\}$. In the former case $m_n = n + 1$ since $ |a_{n + 1} - x | \ge |a_{n + 1} - a_n| - |x - a_n| \ge c - \frac c 3 = \frac c 2 \gt \frac c 3 $. In the latter trivial case $m_n = n$. This proves the sequence diverges.

There is an easier way though. You may consider the [Cauchy Criterion for Convergence](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CGgQFjAJ&url=http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ig/MAS111/Cauchy%2520Criterion.pdf&ei=QP4iU7WFM4aQrQfSyYDwAw&usg=AFQjCNEF8Kfy9akYdATxlNSz4N9Zj9yZfw&bvm=bv.62922401,d.bmk). This example is clearly in violation of it.